# Norwegian character sorting wrongly in sql order by

Tags: sql-server

I just want to sort LastName column in Ent table.

```
select distinct LastName from Ent
order by LastName desc
```

result set contains some Norwegian characters(Å,ø)

[image]

DB and related column collation is 'Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS'

my issue is it's showing 'Aabakken'(which id = 141) 'Aaa'(which id = 142) and 'Aa' (which id = 143) in here.I believe those are in English letters and should be shown in last of the results..

why those values showing there and how can I fix it.

please help me.. thanks

Comment: ORDER BY col COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AA is the last letter in the norwegian alphabet and should come first when you order decending.

Your ordering works just fine with Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS collation. If you want a different ordering, change the collation

```
SELECT x
FROM 
  (values('AA' ),('BB')) x(x) 
ORDER BY
  x collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.. I missed the part which AA is the last character in Norwegian alphebet :) thank you again..

Comment: I just have to clarify this :) AA is an alternative way of writing Å, which is the actual last letter in the norwegian (and the danish) alphabet. Often used in names.